# Keep keyboard from turning off in tablet mode (wayalnd) on 2 in 1 laptop

Tags: keyboard, touchscreen, tablet, libinput

When I put my asus vivobook (running ubuntu 23.04, wayland) to tablet mode, the internal keyboard and touchpad turns off, which is expected behavior. However it also turns off my external (wireless) keyboard, which is plugged in with a usb adapter. How do I prevent the external keyboard from turning off when I'm in tablet mode?

Using `sudo libinput debug-event` I found that the tablet switch event is triggered:

```
-event26  SWITCH_TOGGLE           +9.204s   switch tablet-mode state 1
```

It says in the libinput [documentation](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/switches.html) that the touchpad and internal keyboard e disabled in tablet mode. I imagine that the solution would involve editing this setting, but the docs does not have any info on that.

(Note that since I'm on wayland, solutions invoving xinput is unlikely to work.)

Thanks